# Static Positioned Divs Not Floating At Top Of Parent?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `div`s with content in them, and the 2 with less content are flush with the bottom of the larger `div`.

There's no margin or padding, so I'm  not sure why is this happening?

```css
body {
  width: 100%
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box blue">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
    <p>Blub</p>
    <div class="remainder"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
    <p>I'm working on different ideas for 100% height without using Flexbox, Tables, or a set height on the parent container.</p>
    <hr />
    <p>That's not my question though, why are boxes 1 &amp; 2 floating so far down?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box yellow">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
    <p>Here's some more content</p>
    <div class="remainder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note `&` must be escaped to `&amp;` and `p` elements can't contain `hr` elements. I fixed that in my edit because it was unrelated to the question.

Comment: On the jsFiddle it allowed me to put the <hr> element to the p. Is this not legitimate, bad practice, or bad for cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: [`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)'s content model is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), but [`hr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element) can only be used where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is expected. Moreover, `p`'s closing tag can be omitted if it is immediately followed by `hr` (among others). Therefore, `<p>a<hr />b</p>` becomes `<p>a</p><hr />b</p>`, which is invalid and will be parsed as `<p>a</p><hr />b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `vertical-align` property on the `.box` class is set to `bottom`.  Setting elements to be `inline-block` will allow the vertical align property to affect their positioning.

Just a note: you didn't set the vertical align property yourself, but it is inheriting it from another rule.  Try setting it directly to see the different results.

```
.box {
    vertical-align: top;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they are inline-level elements, their vertical alignment is given by the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property.

```css
.box {
    vertical-align: /* value */;
}
```

Some examples:

- `vertical-align: top`

  ```css
  body {
    width: 100%
  }
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 2%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box blue">
      <h1>Box 1</h1>
      <p>Blub</p>
      <div class="remainder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box green">
      <h1>Box 2</h1>
      <p>I'm working on different ideas for 100% height without using Flexbox, Tables, or a set height on the parent container.</p>
      <hr />
      <p>That's not my question though, why are boxes 1 &amp; 2 floating so far down?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box yellow">
      <h1>Box 3</h1>
      <p>Here's some more content</p>
      <div class="remainder"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- `vertical-align: middle`

  ```css
  body {
    width: 100%
  }
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 2%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box blue">
      <h1>Box 1</h1>
      <p>Blub</p>
      <div class="remainder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box green">
      <h1>Box 2</h1>
      <p>I'm working on different ideas for 100% height without using Flexbox, Tables, or a set height on the parent container.</p>
      <hr />
      <p>That's not my question though, why are boxes 1 &amp; 2 floating so far down?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box yellow">
      <h1>Box 3</h1>
      <p>Here's some more content</p>
      <div class="remainder"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- `vertical-align: bottom`

  ```css
  body {
    width: 100%
  }
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 2%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box blue">
      <h1>Box 1</h1>
      <p>Blub</p>
      <div class="remainder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box green">
      <h1>Box 2</h1>
      <p>I'm working on different ideas for 100% height without using Flexbox, Tables, or a set height on the parent container.</p>
      <hr />
      <p>That's not my question though, why are boxes 1 &amp; 2 floating so far down?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box yellow">
      <h1>Box 3</h1>
      <p>Here's some more content</p>
      <div class="remainder"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```